# Is there anything that ext4. btrfs, or F2FS can do for a usb3.0 thumb drive that fat does not do?

Tags: filesystem, ext4, btrfs

I don't particularly care about cross platform. I have a thumb drive, and what to know if there is anything to gain from formatting it to ext4, btrfs, or f2fs.

Thanks

Comment: Depends on what you expect out of the flash drive and what you feel are the advantages / disadvantages of each file system and what you are trying to optimize. fat has the advantages also. At the end of the day, the question as written is more a matter of an opinion then support or technical specifications.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Bodhi. From my perspective; "Advantages" are not an opinion. If a Bus is the bottle neck in these cases, then there is no speed advantage. If BTRFS's features are not usable on a thumb, then it has no feature advantages either.

Comment: it is unclear from your question what it is you are asking, what features do you expeCt from your file system. size? speed? cross platform compatibility? Snapshots?

Comment: Most USBs are FAT as that works with everything. If there is something that fat doesn't cover, please [edit] your question to explain why not.

Comment: @Tim Thanks for the tip; I took your advice and editted the question.

Comment: EXT4 is better then, better support for permissions and journalling and file size etc.

Comment: Are you talking of FAT32 or exFAT?

Comment: @muru I assume fat32; isn't that what most thumb drives are formatted in?

Comment: BTRFS better than FAT, because supports compression, which could be crucial because flash sticks tends to have slow IO.

Answer (score 1):

FAT32 has an obvious and glaring limitation:

- File size limit: 4 GB.
  That, for me, is show-stopper. And possibly the only reason I still use FAT32, would be that some startup disk creators (perhaps the Startup Disk Creator as well) format the drive to FAT32.

Given cross-platform support is not a limitation, there is absolutely no reason to use FAT32. In fact the only reason to use `ext4` is that `btrfs` is not quite there yet.